# Allow guests to a VS Code Live Share session to run Python extension 'cells'

Tags: visual-studio-code

When guests in a VS Code Live Share session try to run VS Code Python extension 'cells', they will get the following message in an error pop-up dialog in the lower right:

```
The host doesn’t allow running this command. 
If needed, ask them to enable it.
```

Clicking on the "More info" button of the pop-up dialog, directs the guest to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/reference/security.  I cannot find on this page where it describes how to allow guests to use certain features of particular VS Code extensions.

As a host, how do I allow guests to my VS Code Live Share session to run VS Code Python extension 'cells'?

Answer (score 3):

Analogous to Guest Debugging (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/live-share/issues/2154), there is an option to "Allow Guest Command Control" in the VSCode Live Share extension settings (in VSCode, open the extensions sidebar - under "Installed", click on the settings wheel next to "Live Share" - Extension Settings). Enabling this should do the trick (could not test this, yet).
There may be some additional issues depending on version: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/live-share/issues/3121

Answer (score 0):

This settings in settings.json worked for me:

```
{
  "liveshare.allowGuestDebugControl": true,
  "liveshare.allowGuestTaskControl": true,
  "liveshare.languages.allowGuestCommandControl": true,
  "liveshare.openSharedServers": false,
  "liveshare.publishWorkspaceInfo": true,
}
```